# Black Screen after Windows 10 Update no motherboard logo, no cursor, no safe mode, nothing

Tags: windows-10, black-screen-of-death

First of all, I'm not an expert but a pretty decent hack who finds answers on forums that fix most everyday issues we run into.  I "successfully" updated to Windows 10 from 8.1 on a Gateway SX2110G-UW23 Desktop that was purchased roughly two years ago.  I went through the whole "Hi.  I'm Cortana. Blah, blah, blah." and walked away feeling that I was good.  That night the computer hibernated (as it does every night because I never changed it to not hibernate) and upon powering up the next day I got a black screen with no motherboard logo, no cursor, no ability to get into safe mode, nothing at all.
So far I have tried:

- F8 on start up.  No dice.  Thinking this is due to fast start up but not worried about that since I can't do anything about it now
- Put in a Windows 10 boot USB.  No luck here since I think there is a setting that has to look to USB to boot and probably wasn't set before upgrade.  Again, not worried about that since I can't do anything about it now.
- Plugged in separate "monitor" - aka 32 inch LCD TV - to HDMI.  Used Windows+P to try to switch monitors.
- Tried to interrupt startup 3X in a row to force failed login and recovery mode.
- Tried several suggestion starting with a blind login.

It's an AMD Radeon HD 7310 Graphics card, so I assume it's not the NVidia driver issue, plus there was no KSOD until after it powered back up, not during the upgrade itself.

Too many hours on forums for a computer that cost $169 for surfing, e-mail and taxes.  BUT there's boat loads of music, pictures and tax files from probably the past ten years and although I have backed up I'm sure it's been a while...leave the chastising, I know, I know.  Any other solutions welcome.

Comment: Pull the drive from the PC, connect it to another pc and delete the hiberfil.sys file on the root of the system partition, put it back in the pc and see if it will boot.

Comment: Does your motherboard have integrated graphics? Can you try plugging a screen into that? If that works you will need to replace the AMD card.